# Is it possible to make <script> tags visible?

Tags: html, css, visibility

I would like to make a `script` tag visible. Is this possible?

Comment: &lt;script&gt; ? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I can almost guarantee there's a better way to achieve whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: I have no idea why you'd want to do this but great question! I'd never even thought of this as an option..

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you would want to do that, but simple CSS should do the trick:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Sample page</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    script {
      display:block;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      console.log("why?");
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0v2wo3a2/

**Edit:** If your script is in the `<head>`, you'll have to make the head visible, too:

```
<style type="text/css">
  head, script {
    display:block;
  }
</style>
```

Also, as Mike pointed out in the comments, you could be looking for this option:

```
&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;console.log("why?");<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;}<br/>
&lt;/script&gt;
```

This looks bad, but it is more self explanitory in this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0v2wo3a2/1/

Comment: @Adrift Are you sure?  It works fine when I load the code into an HTML file on my server.

Comment: Not working for me, because `head` is hidden (`display: none;`) in most browsers.

Comment: The `<script>` tag can be included in the body as well, not just in the head, see edit.

Comment: Oh well in that case you're right. I assumed the scripts were in the `head` for OP. Might wanna point out that distinction.

Comment: OK.  I added an edit to reflect that option.  I really can't see the purpose for either option.

Comment: Instead of the `nbsp`, you could use CSS to preserve the whitespace. Similar to this: https://jsfiddle.net/0v2wo3a2/2/ (but with the html entities for script)